# Replace view with subquery

Tags: sql, view, subquery

I have a table with this data:

```
ID | Date           | MacroID  | FunctionID
---------------------------------------
1  | 1.1.2010 10:00 | core     | coreP1
2  | 2.1.2010 11:11 | main     | mainP7
3  | 1.1.2010 17:01 | core     | coreP2
4  | 3.1.2011 21:00 | top      | topP7
5  | 1.1.2010 11:11 | left     | leftP0
```

and I need to get:

```
Date     | Sum_Macro |
----------------------
1.1.2010 | 2
2.1.2010 | 1
3.1.2010 | 1
```

where: 
for any DISTINCT Date (stripped time) I need a sum of DISTINCT Macro occurrences.
At 1.1.2010 the Macro core and left was run, so 2... etc

I can do this using a view, but I'm sure there is more easy way:

```
CREATE VIEW Days_Macros AS
SELECT DISTINCT MacroID, COUNT(MacroID) AS MacroCnt, CONVERT(varchar, tStamp, 103) AS x
FROM TRADStatMacro
GROUP BY MacroID, CONVERT(varchar, tStamp, 103)
```

which gives me:

```
MacroID  | MacroCnt | x
------------------------------
core     | 2        | 1.1.2010
main     | 1        | 2.1.2010
top      | 1        | 3.1.2010
left     | 1        | 1.1.2011
```

and than:

```
SELECT DISTINCT X, COUNT(MacroCnt) AS Y FROM Test
GROUP BY X
```

gives me the result.
...too complicated, ideas anybody?

Thanx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sample data:

```
if object_id('tempdb..#tab') is not null drop table #tab

create table #tab (
    id int,
    date datetime,
    macroId varchar(6),
    fynctionId varchar(10)
)

insert into #tab
select 1 , '1.1.2010 10:00', 'core', 'coreP1' union
select 2 , '2.1.2010 11:11', 'main', 'mainP7' union
select 3 , '1.1.2010 17:01', 'core', 'coreP2' union
select 4 , '3.1.2011 21:00', 'top ', 'topP7' union
select 5 , '1.1.2010 11:11', 'left', 'leftP0'
```

query (edit, after clarification):

```
select 
    dateadd(dd, 0, datediff(dd, 0, date)) as Date, 
    count(distinct MacroId) as Sum_Macro
from #tab
group by dateadd(dd, 0, datediff(dd, 0, date))
```

Comment: Hi Michal,

Perhaps I failed to express myself clearly. I need an output with distinct dates, and sum of distinct macroID per that day. Even if different function of the same MacroID apears more than once per day its still should be counted only once: 

SUM of DISTINCT MacroID / Day

Comment: I've changed the query, now it gives exact result set as you have been asking for.

Answer (score 0):

I tend to be a fan of CTEs for this purpose (with are basically inline views). It looks like you're using SQL Server, so you could do this:

```
WITH counts AS
(
    SELECT DISTINCT MacroID, COUNT(MacroID) AS MacroCnt, CONVERT(varchar, tStamp, 103) AS x
    FROM TRADStatMacro
    GROUP BY MacroID, CONVERT(varchar, tStamp, 103)
)
SELECT DISTINCT X, COUNT(MacroCnt) AS Y FROM counts
GROUP BY X
```

*Questions: did you mean for the second `COUNT()` to actually be a `SUM()`?*

But your query could be simplified. You don't need the `DISTINCT` if you're already grouping by the columns that make the record unique. And you aren't using the `MacroId` field other than in the aggregate `COUNT()` function, so you could eliminate it and probably simplify everything down to:

```
SELECT CONVERT(varchar, tStamp, 103) AS X, COUNT(MacroID)
FROM TRADStatMacro
GROUP BY MacroID, CONVERT(varchar, tStamp, 103)
```

Comment: You don't need to group by MacroID in your second query.

Comment: Thx for response.
What is the Test reference in your query?
PS: yes I'm using SQL 2008

Comment: @PetrŠimůnek: Sorry, that was a typo; I corrected the example.

Comment: Thanx as well man,
I have just used your approach in another problem I had :O)
"Learn something every day..."